# How to use case statement in Sql server on a particular condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-order-by

So I have a table that looks like this

| Name | Group | DATE | control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | NULL | 20 April 2023 | Null |
| XYZ | A | 19 April 2023 | Null |
| YYY | A | 19 April 2023 | Y |

and the query  for this is suppose as follows:

```
 select Name,Group,Date,control
 from  Customer
 order by date desc
```

What I want for my table to look like that it first sorts the data using date in desc order but for the cases where group has some value like in the table above there are two cases with group `A`, I want the one with control check `Y` to be on top of that group so basically order will remain the same. Just in case of group, the case with control unit Y should come first and then the remaining cases.

My table will now look like this

| Name | Group | DATE | control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | NULL | 20 April 2023 | Null |
| YYY | A | 19 April 2023 | Y |
| XYZ | A | 19 April 2023 | Null |

I tried using case statement in order by like this

```
 select Name,Group,Date,control
 from  Customer
 order by date,case when control='Y' then 1 else 0 desc
```

But this shows the case YYY at top . I want ABC to remain at top and in the cases of group only, the case with control check Y  should come on top.

Update:
Before:

order by clause:
order by e.dateon desc

[image: DataBefore]

After:

order by clause:

```
 ORDER BY CONVERT(date, e.dateon) desc,
  CASE WHEN c.IsControlUnit = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc
```

[image: DataAfter]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253257/discussion-on-question-by-unknown-how-to-use-case-statement-in-sql-server-on-a-p); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess what you want.

You can try `ORDER BY` DATE first and then use `CASE WHEN` to further sort your data.
I can only advise not to use keywords as column names.

```
SELECT Name, 
       "Group", 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), "DATE", 106) AS "DATE",
       control
FROM tab
ORDER BY 
  "DATE" DESC,
  CASE WHEN "Group" = 'A' AND control = 'Y' THEN 0
       WHEN "Group" = 'A' THEN 1
       ELSE 2
  END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CZO6K8Yd)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to sort by date (without time) first, then by the `Y`, then by the date and time, all descending

```sql
select
  Name,
  GroupName,
  isControlUnit,
  dateon
from Cases
order by
  cast(dateon as date) desc,
  isControlUnit desc,
  dateon desc;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/_OHnlh_1)